# Make the size of a TextView equal across devices and density

Tags: android, textview

I've been searching at this but can't find a solution. I have a custom `TextView` which goes into an `ArrayAdapter`, the size of the text is `18sp`. I've tested this on two emulators: 7" mdpi and 4.7" xhdpi and the difference is pretty noticeable. It basically ruins my layout. I'm developing for version 4+.

[image: Text on different screens]

The smaller one is too small for the mdpi display and the first one is too big. How can I make the text display equal (or with very minimal discrepancy) between these two devices? The font settings are set to normal.

Comment: Instead of using 18sp, have you tried 18dp?

Comment: @epsilondelta The result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `res/values/dimens.xml` to define your text size like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then you can use multiple [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) for the `res/values` folder to provide a different `dimens.xml` for each screen size. For example:

`res/values-small/dimens.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">24sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`res/values-large/dimens.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And apply your dimension like this in a layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
          android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
```

#### Optional:

Refer to your dimension in your `res/values/styles.xml` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="my_text">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
    </style>
<resources>
```

And apply your style like this in a layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
          style="@style/my_text"/>
```

Comment: After reading more it should be mentioned that these are deprecated in favor of a [different technique](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

Answer (score 0):

Creating different `values` directories for specific densities and have the values set in dimen.xml.

For example:

Create `values-mdpi` and `values-xhdpi` and each of this directories will contain `dimen.xml` in which you specify the size you want to use when the appropriate density is chosen.